# C# Override an abstract class' function with a different one with a "Class Type" return type

Tags: c#, class, types, virtual, abstract

I am trying to create a class based on an abstract class and overwrite a function contained in the base class with another one that has a return type of "T" which is a type passed by the class.

e.g:

```
public abstract class DayInfo
{
    public virtual void GetInfo()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class DayInfo<T> : DayInfo
{
    private T info;
    public DayInfo(T data)
    {
        info = data;
    }

    public T GetInfo() // << This
    {
        return info;
    }
}
```

Examples:

## 1

```
DayInfo info = new DayInfo<String>("Blah");
String stuff = info.GetInfo();
```

## 2

```
DayInfo info = new DayInfo<int>(25);
int stuff = info.GetInfo();
```

Is there **any way** to achieve this?

Edit 1:
I forgot to precise that I didn't used a class-passed type in the base class because I wanted to be able to use it as a generic type without having to define any type.

e.g:

```
public SortedDictionary<int, DayInfo> Data = new SortedDictionary<int, DayInfo>();
```

Edit 2:

Also, the point of the virtual function in the base class is that it will make the child classes throw an exception if the GetInfo() function is accessed but isn't overridden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be produced with [NVI pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern):

```
public abstract class DayInfo
{
  protected virtual void GetInfoCore() {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  // or
  // protected abstract void GetInfoCore();

  public void GetInfo() {
    GetInfoCore();
  }
}

public class DayInfo<T> : DayInfo
{
  private T info;

  public DayInfo(T data) {
    info = data;
  }

  public new T GetInfo() { // << This
    return info;
  }

  protected override void GetInfoCore() {
    GetInfo();
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason... it doesn't work. Defined variables aren't able to get the expected data. e.g: new DayInfo<String>("Blah").GetInfo() will STILL be a void function.

Comment: It would perform the appropriate function call in theory but wouldn't the compiler cry foul as `GetInfo` has a return type `void` if used as the base class?

Comment: @McAden Yes, it would require casting to work, but I'm precisely trying to avoid that. e.g: ((DayInfo<String>)info).GetInfo()

Comment: @LouisTakePILLz Are you sure? I was tried my code and it works well: http://ideone.com/5tJnhN no castings required, wen you works with variable of type DayInfo<String>.

Comment: @ViacheslavIvanov Ah I see you used "var item = new DayInfo<string>("aaa")" instead of "DayInfo item = new DayInfo<string>("aaa")". That's why I couldn't get it to work. Well then, it seems to work fine except that I had to make a few changes to get it to work the way I want to, see: http://pastebin.com/Mygx705Q

Comment: @LouisTakePILLz If you need to have a some result on GetInfo() in base class DayInfo (if you wan to works with base type in compile time), make some changes: http://ideone.com/3Vc1Nz

Answer (score 1):

this is the way to achieve your goal:

```
public abstract class DayInfoA<T>
{
    public virtual T GetInfo()
    {
        .......
    }
}

public class DayInfoB<T> : DayInfoA<T>
{
    private T info;
    public DayInfoB(T data)
    {
        info = data;
    }

    public override T GetInfo() // << This
    {
      .........
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
        DayInfoB<int> info = new DayInfoB<int>(25);
        int stuff = info.GetInfo();
```

Comment: I forgot to precise that I didn't used a class-passed type in the base class because I wanted to be able to use it as a generic type without having to define any type. e.g: public SortedDictionary<int, DayInfo> Data = new SortedDictionary<int, DayInfo>();

Comment: @LouisTakePILLz for such a general `DayInfo` what should `GetInfo`'s return type be?

Comment: GetInfo's return type is T. what you declare in new new DayInfoB<xxx>, xxx is the data type.

Comment: @Giswin Oh, it can be anything, it could contain a class, string, int... anything really.

Comment: you are right. it can be any thing, this is the powerful part of template

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you declare `GetInfo()` as `dynamic`?
This way the casting should be automatic. The only downside is that you'd lost the compiler assertions and if the variable that stores `GetInfo()` value can't do the cast, it'll throw a runtime error.

For example:

```
public abstract class DayInfo {
    public abstract dynamic GetInfo();
}

public class DayInfo<T> : DayInfo {
    private readonly T _info;
    public DayInfo(T info) {
        _info = info;
    }
    public override dynamic GetInfo() {
        return _info;
    }
}
```

You also could declare something like `GetInfo<T>(ref T result)`, this way you can omit the `T` type from the method call and let the compiler infer it at runtime, the only downside is that you should pass the variable to store the result as an argument instead to get it returned by the method.

Comment: You kinda lost me at the dynamic part... (I don't get how this could work). Could you provide an example?

Comment: The edit I provided passed some simple tests based on OPs examples: 
`    DayInfo infoA = new DayInfo<string>("Blah");     string stuffA = infoA.GetInfo();    Assert.AreEqual("Blah", stuffA);    DayInfo infoB = new DayInfo<int>(25);    int stuffB = infoB.GetInfo();    Assert.AreEqual(25, stuffB);    SortedDictionary<int, DayInfo> data = new SortedDictionary<int, DayInfo>();`

Comment: You could also make the base GetInfo() throw an exception as virtual, still, if you desired.

Comment: @maxwellb This is perfect! It indeed works, Thanks a lot! Edit: I did edit it to throw an exception, thanks again.

Comment: @maxwellb Actually, I might have been celebrating too soon, it's not over yet.. There's still a problem, I can't identify what type of value it is being returned. For instance, DayInfo info = new DayInfo<DayOfWeek>(DayOfWeek.Saturday); var blah = info.GetInfo(); Debug.WriteLine(blah); will throw an exception of type "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException", but if we replace "var blah" by "DayOfWeek blah", it will successfully print "blah" in the debug log.

Comment: Sorry LouisTakePILLz, I didn't got it, if you already know the type of T type, why would you use "var"instead? The error shows because dynamic types are "internal", i.e. the compiler can only infer them within the same assembly, but if you already know the type of the value you are expecting (as in the examples of your original question), then you should have no problem by declaring "DayOfWeek blah". P.S., thanks @maxwellb for the example.

Comment: @EmmanuelValle The thing is, I haven't been able to detect their type and cast them to the appropriate type.. in this example, I do know what type of value is stored, but concretely, when this snippet will be fully integrated in my code, I won't be able to know which are what...

Comment: @LouisTakePILLz At some point in the code, you will need to assume a type. Or cast to a middle type. C# is a strongly typed language, even with dynamic extensions. You may be able in your previous example to use `dynamic` instead of `var`, but somewhere, you'll have to presume a type, or use a method which takes a least-derived type. Without seeing the actual application, it's hard to say what's "best," but you're definitely going to have to solve the hard problem _somewhere_, and avoiding type-casting is just shifting the problem around.

Comment: @maxwellb Thanks for your answer, but I have already made my choice; I won't be using dynamics. At least now I know what dynamics are for :)

Answer (score 0):

No, not like it looks like you're wanting it (assuming you don't want to or cant alter the base class declaration).  In order for the function to resolve to a polymorphic call, you need to have the same signature and return type.  Otherwise it wont resolve the function polymorphically, it'll just call the base class version of the function since that's what it sees you calling (and the variable you've assigned your instance to is of the base class type).

You CAN do this, but it's pretty ugly:

```
        DayInfo info = new DayInfo<String>("Blah");
        String stuff = ((DayInfo<string>)info).GetInfo();
```

Comment: Indeed it is. Although, It seems to be the only solution (yet).

Answer (score 0):

No, because the functions won't match up with different function signatures.

What you can do is define it like so:

```
public abstract class DayInfo
{
    public virtual object GetInfo()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and in the derived class like this:

```
public object GetInfo() // << This
{
    return info;
}
```

Then they would both have the same signature and the polymorphism would match up.
However, on the other end a cast will be required:

```
DayInfo info = new DayInfo<int>(25);
int stuff = (int)info.GetInfo();
```

Edit: As an aside unless there's more to it I'd make that into an interface or if the `GetInfo` really does nothing make the `GetInfo` purely abstract.

```
public abstract object GetInfo();
```

Comment: Well, in this situation, I'm trying to avoid using casts. So this doesn't make it very useful.

Comment: I feel this is the best you're going to get. If you're using it as a base class the compiler has no way of knowing the subclass' implementation. Can you find any other class in the framework that acts the way you're asking?

Comment: Unfortunately, no I don't.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a covariant interface instead of, or in addition to, a base class:

```
void Main()
{
    IDayInfo dayInfo = new DayInfo<string>("hi!");
    object info = dayInfo.GetInfo(); //info == "hi!"
}
public interface IDayInfo
{
    object GetInfo();
}
public interface IDayInfo<out T> : IDayInfo
{
    new T GetInfo();
}

public class DayInfo<T> : IDayInfo<T>
{
    private T info;
    public DayInfo(T data)
    {
        info = data;
    }

    public T GetInfo()
    {
        return info;
    }
    object IDayInfo.GetInfo()
    {
        return this.GetInfo();
    }
}
```

(see [Variance in Generic Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx) for info on what covariance/contravariance are)

Note that `object info` (in my second line in `Main`) is as precise as you can get without casting in this example. Once you store the `DayInfo<string>` object in an `IDayInfo<object>` variable/field, as I did (and as you'd like to do in your dictionary), the stronger typing of `string` is, in a sense, forgotten and cannot be restored without a cast.

**Update:** added `IDayInfo` interface.

Comment: Isn't there any way to not have to use a defined template variable? e.g: IDayInfo dayInfo = new DayInfo<String>("hi!");

Comment: Only if you have another interface, `IDayInfo` (you might have `IDayInfo<T> : IDayInfo`, or let them be separate). I don't like this approach because it means that your implementing classes have to provide `object` implementations, even if it doesn't make sense to. If you're just concerned about typing out the type name, you could make a using alias directive (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx), but I wouldn't advise this for such a simple thing. If your real generic type is much longer, with multiple type parameters, it might make sense.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work (for IDayInfo<T> : IDayInfo), could you provide an example?

Comment: @LouisTakePILLz added to my answer. I meant `:` as in "extends", not as in a foreach loop, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Actually, I might be the one confusing you; by "(for IDayInfo<T> : IDayInfo)", I wasn't referencing to a "for" loop, I was actually saying "I can't seem to get this code to work FOR "IDayInfo<T> : IDayInfo" ". Sorry for my lack of clarity. Although, I think I better try casting my objects, it will be much more easier, but less pretty :/. Thanks anyways.